Stage 2 Bootloader Does Not Jump Into the Kernel Entry Correctly
I am developing a custom bootloader for my 64-bit OS in x86_64 NASM on macOS environment using QEMU. The bootloader is a 2-stage, and is designed to load operating systems from disks. I am experiencing issues where the bootloader fails to properly jump to the kernel entry point after loading it into memory.
Current Behavior

The bootloader successfully reads and loads Stage 2 into memory ("Stage 2 loaded successfully!").
It then attempts to jump to the kernel located at the higher-half address 0xFFFFFFFF80000000
The bootloader just freezes when it tries to load the kernel

Relevant Code:
first_stage.asm:
; First stage bootloader
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

start:
    ; Set up segments and stack
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7C00      ; Set stack just below the bootloader

    ; Store boot drive number
    mov [bootDrive], dl

    ; Load Stage 2 (3 sectors, starting from sector 2)
    mov ah, 0x02        ; BIOS read sector function
    mov al, 3           ; Number of sectors to read
    mov ch, 0           ; Cylinder number
    mov cl, 2           ; Start from sector 2
    mov dh, 0           ; Head number
    mov bx, 0x7E00      ; Load Stage 2 right after the bootloader

    int 0x13            ; BIOS interrupt to read disk
    jc disk_error       ; Jump if error

    ; Print success message
    mov si, successMsg
    call print_string

    ; Pass boot drive number to second stage and jump
    mov dl, [bootDrive] ; Load boot drive number
    jmp 0x0000:0x7E00

disk_error:
    mov si, diskErrorMsg
    call print_string
    mov ah, 0x0E        ; Print the error code in AH
    int 0x10
    cli
    hlt

print_string:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz done
    mov ah, 0x0E
    int 0x10
    jmp print_string
done:
    ret

diskErrorMsg db 'Disk Error!', 13, 10, 0
successMsg db 'Stage 2 loaded successfully!', 13, 10, 0
bootDrive db 0

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xAA55   ; Boot signature

second_stage.asm:
; Second stage bootloader
; Second stage bootloader
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7E00]

start:
    ; Set up segments
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ax, 0x9000      ; Use segment 0x9000 (0x90000 physical address)
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0xFFFF      ; Set stack pointer to the top of the segment

    ; Print initial success message
    mov si, stage2Msg
    call print_string_16

    ; Enable A20 line for mem access beyond 1MB
    call enable_A20

    ; Load the kernel
    call load_kernel

    ; Load GDT and switch to protected mode
    call enable_protected_mode
enable_A20:
    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al
    ret

load_kernel:
    mov ah, 0x02        ; BIOS read sector function
    mov al, 9           ; Number of sectors to read (adjust as needed)
    mov ch, 0           ; Cylinder number
    mov cl, 5           ; Start from sector 5
    mov dh, 0           ; Head number
    ; DL already contains the boot drive number from the first stage
    mov bx, 0x8000      ; Load starting at 0x8000

    int 0x13            ; BIOS interrupt to read disk
    jc disk_error       ; Jump if error
    ret

enable_protected_mode:
    cli                 ; Disable interrupts
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]

    ; Enable protected mode
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1           ; Set PE (Protection Enable) bit
    mov cr0, eax

    ; Enable PAE
    mov eax, cr4
    or eax, 1 << 5      ; Set PAE bit
    mov cr4, eax

    ; Enter protected mode
    jmp 0x08:protected_mode_entry

[BITS 32]
protected_mode_entry:
    mov ax, 0x10        ; Data segment selector
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax

    ; Set up stack for protected mode
    mov esp, 0x90000

    ; Debug print
    mov esi, protected_mode_msg
    call print_string_pm

    ; Set up paging for long mode
    call setup_paging

    ; Enable long mode
    call enable_long_mode

    ; Load 64-bit GDT
    lgdt [gdt64_descriptor]

    ; Jump to long mode entry
    jmp 0x08:long_mode_entry

setup_paging:
    ; Set up 4-level paging
    mov edi, 0x1000
    mov cr3, edi
    xor eax, eax
    mov ecx, 4096
    rep stosd
    mov edi, cr3

    mov dword [edi], 0x2003      ; PML4[0] -> PDPT
    add edi, 0x1000
    mov dword [edi], 0x3003      ; PDPT[0] -> PD
    add edi, 0x1000
    mov dword [edi], 0x4003      ; PD[0] -> PT
    add edi, 0x1000

    mov ebx, 0x00000003          ; Entry flags
    mov ecx, 512                 ; Number of entries

    .set_entry:
        mov dword [edi], ebx     ; Set entry
        add ebx, 0x1000          ; Next page
        add edi, 8               ; Next entry
        loop .set_entry

    ret

enable_long_mode:
    ; Enable long mode in IA32_EFER MSR
    mov ecx, 0xC0000080
    rdmsr
    or eax, 1 << 8      ; Set Long Mode Enable (LME) bit
    wrmsr
    ret

[BITS 64]
long_mode_entry:
    ; Set up segment registers for long mode
    mov ax, 0x10        ; Data segment selector
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax

    ; Set up stack for long mode
    mov rsp, 0x90000

    ; Print long mode message
    mov rsi, long_mode_msg
    call print_string_lm

    mov rax, 0xFFFFFFFF80000000   ; Kernel address
    jmp rax

[BITS 16]
print_string_16:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz .done
    mov ah, 0x0E        ; BIOS teletype function
    int 0x10
    jmp print_string_16
.done:
    ret

[BITS 32]
print_string_pm:
    push eax
    push ebx
.loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz .done
    mov ah, 0x0F        ; Text attribute for character
    mov ebx, 0xB8000    ; VGA video memory address
    mov [ebx], ax       ; Write character to VGA memory
    add ebx, 2          ; Move to next character
    jmp .loop
.done:
    pop ebx
    pop eax
    ret

[BITS 64]
print_string_lm:
    push rax
    push rbx
.loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz .done
    mov ah, 0x0F        ; Text attribute for character
    mov rbx, 0xB8000    ; VGA video memory address
    mov [rbx], ax       ; Write character to VGA memory
    add rbx, 2          ; Move to next character
    jmp .loop
.done:
    pop rbx
    pop rax
    ret

[BITS 16]
disk_error:
    mov si, diskErrorMsg
    call print_string_16
    cli
    hlt

; Data
stage2Msg db 'Entered Stage 2', 13, 10, 0
protected_mode_msg db 'Entered Protected Mode', 0
long_mode_msg db 'Entered Long Mode', 0
diskErrorMsg db 'Disk Error While Reading Kernel!', 13, 10, 0

; GDT for Protected Mode
gdt_start:
    dq 0x0000000000000000 ; Null descriptor
    dq 0x00CF9A000000FFFF ; 32-bit code descriptor
    dq 0x00CF92000000FFFF ; 32-bit data descriptor
gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

; GDT for Long Mode
gdt64_start:
    dq 0x0000000000000000 ; Null descriptor
    dq 0x00AF9A000000FFFF ; 64-bit code descriptor
    dq 0x00AF92000000FFFF ; 64-bit data descriptor
gdt64_end:

gdt64_descriptor:
    dw gdt64_end - gdt64_start - 1
    dq gdt64_start

times 1536 - ($ - $$) db 0 ; Pad to 3 sectors

linker.ld:
ENTRY(kernel_start)

KERNEL_VMA = 0xFFFFFFFF80000000;
KERNEL_LMA = 0x8000;

SECTIONS
{
    . = KERNEL_VMA;

    .text ALIGN(4K) : AT(ADDR(.text) - KERNEL_VMA + KERNEL_LMA)
    {
        *(.text*)
    }

    .rodata ALIGN(4K) : AT(ADDR(.rodata) - KERNEL_VMA + KERNEL_LMA)
    {
        *(.rodata*)
    }

    .data ALIGN(4K) : AT(ADDR(.data) - KERNEL_VMA + KERNEL_LMA)
    {
        *(.data*)
    }

    .bss ALIGN(4K) : AT(ADDR(.bss) - KERNEL_VMA + KERNEL_LMA)
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss*)
    }

    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.eh_frame)
        *(.comment)
    }
}

Makefile:
ARCH ?= x86_64

ASM=nasm
CC=$(ARCH)-elf-gcc
LD=$(ARCH)-elf-ld
OBJCOPY=x86_64-elf-objcopy
STRIP=x86_64-elf-strip
NASMFLAGS=-f bin
NASMFLAGS_ELF64=-f elf64
CFLAGS=-ffreestanding -nostdlib -mno-red-zone -Wall -Wextra -g -O2 -mcmodel=kernel
LDFLAGS=-T linker.ld

BUILD_DIR=bin
BOOT_DIR=boot/$(ARCH)
KERNEL_DIR=kernel
ARCH_DIR=kernel/arch/

KERNEL_BIN=$(BUILD_DIR)/kernel-$(ARCH).bin
KERNEL_ELF=$(BUILD_DIR)/kernel-$(ARCH).elf
BOOTLOADER_IMG=$(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader-$(ARCH).img

KERNEL_C=$(KERNEL_DIR)/kernel.c
KERNEL_ENTRY=$(ARCH_DIR)/entry-$(ARCH).asm

FIRST_STAGE=$(BOOT_DIR)/first_stage.asm
SECOND_STAGE=$(BOOT_DIR)/second_stage.asm

$(BUILD_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR)/first_stage-$(ARCH).bin: $(FIRST_STAGE) | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(ASM) $(NASMFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/second_stage-$(ARCH).bin: $(SECOND_STAGE) | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(ASM) $(NASMFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/entry-$(ARCH).o: $(KERNEL_ENTRY) | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(ASM) $(NASMFLAGS_ELF64) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.o: $(KERNEL_C) | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(KERNEL_ELF): $(BUILD_DIR)/entry-$(ARCH).o $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.o | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(KERNEL_BIN): $(KERNEL_ELF) | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

$(BOOTLOADER_IMG): $(BUILD_DIR)/first_stage-$(ARCH).bin $(BUILD_DIR)/second_stage-$(ARCH).bin $(KERNEL_BIN)
    dd if=/dev/zero of=$(BOOTLOADER_IMG) bs=512 count=131072
    dd if=$(BUILD_DIR)/first_stage-$(ARCH).bin of=$(BOOTLOADER_IMG) bs=512 seek=0 conv=notrunc
    dd if=$(BUILD_DIR)/second_stage-$(ARCH).bin of=$(BOOTLOADER_IMG) bs=512 seek=2 conv=notrunc
    dd if=$(KERNEL_BIN) of=$(BOOTLOADER_IMG) bs=512 seek=34 conv=notrunc

run: $(BOOTLOADER_IMG)
    qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=bin/bootloader-$(ARCH).img,format=raw -monitor stdio

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o $(BUILD_DIR)/*.bin $(BUILD_DIR)/*.img $(KERNEL_ELF)

all: $(BOOTLOADER_IMG)

rerun: clean all run

Question: What did I do wrong?
PS: The kernel is small enough to fit within the allocated sectors (190 bytes), and it is allocated correctly in the expected address. The first stage boot is at 0x7C00.
I tried debugging using print statements in VGA however there was nothing on the emulator console. There were also warnings during assemble as well:
boot/x86_64/second_stage.asm:172: warning: signed dword immediate exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]
boot/x86_64/second_stage.asm:172: warning: dword data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]

Edit 1: It seems that load_kernel does not return after being called and BIOS interrupt caused issue(?).
Edit 2: The registers appeared to be right and correctly jumped into 64-bit. However, the kernel is not loaded correctly in the memory but no error was thrown (memory inaccessible at 0xFFFFFFFF80000000.

I tried debugging using print statements in VGA - the beauty of using emulators instead of real hardware is that we can easily attach a debugger (or use Bochs's built-in debugger) and single-step and look at registers!  Don't waste your time with debug-prints in assembly except for much higher-level stuff than this, especially for bootloader stuff.   (Progress messages like "stage 2 loaded" are good, but debug-prints no)

You forgot to say which line is 172, but or rax, 0x80000000 produces that warning, and actually assembles as or rax,0xffffffff80000000.  (Only mov can use a 64-bit immediate, and immediates are always sign-extended not zero-extended for computation instructions.)  IDK if CR0 silently ignores those high bits your code tries to set, or if you need something like bts rax, 31 for future-proofing.  (On current CPUs the high 32 bits of CR0 will be 0 so you can just or eax, 1<<31)

I'm confused by the code. It seems your stage1 has an org 0x8000 instead of org 0x7c00. You then do jmp 0x0000:0x8000 and have 32-bit code there (bits 32). But you are still in 16-bit real mode and not 32-bit protected mode as the comments suggest. Where do you enter 32-bit protected mode?

There are other issues besides what I mentioned. Like the .data section not being accessible to the first 512 bytes in the first sector of the bootloader. There also seems to be a discrepancy between where your bootloader and other stages are physically loaded in memory at runtime and where the assembler thinks they are. The code as posted has me scratching my head. I think there are things missing? Is the code you posted 1st stage or 2nd stage? What you have posted is not a [mcve] and is hard to follow what you are actually doing or attempting to do.

Lots of issues. Switch to 32 bit mode is completely missing, print_string_pm should be 32 bits code but compiled as 64 bits, (presumed) kernel addresses are not mapped and kernel is not loaded anywhere either.

@PeterCordes I've changed the 172nd line, thank you,

@MichaelPetch I might have accidentally pasted the first stage code in the same codeblock as the second. The code should be updated by now.

Update: There is a disk error when the program tried reading the kernel at the designated address

I am getting a clearer picture with the code you are showing now (in the update). You have a first stage which is loaded at 0x7c00. You have a second stage that expects to be loaded at 0x7e00 by first stage. First off I think dd if=$(BUILD_DIR)/second_stage-$(ARCH).bin of=$(BOOTLOADER_IMG) bs=512 seek=2 conv=notrunc is wrong. The seek value is 0 based with DD. So the second sector should be seek=1 (not seek=2).

In first_stage.asm you want to jump to the second stage at 0x7e00. But you actually jump to 0x8000 instead. In first_stage.asm I think you want to start loading at 0x7e00 so mov bx, 0x8000 should be mov bx, 0x7E00. Then jmp 0x0000:0x8000 should be jmp 0x0000:0x7E00.

In second_stage.asm you do a mov dl, [bootDrive] ; Drive number before int 0x13. The problem is that the bootDrive variable in second_stage.asm is not the same address as the one in first_stage.asm. So you will always load a 0 into DL. If booting from anything other than a floppy this won't work. Remove mov dl, [bootDrive] ; Drive number from before the int 0x13 in second_stage.asm and move it right before you do jmp 0x0000:0x7e00 in first_stage.asm. That way DL will have the boot drive number in it when the second_stage starts running.

I also believe this is wrong: dd if=$(KERNEL_BIN) of=$(BOOTLOADER_IMG) bs=512 seek=34 conv=notrunc. Your second_stage.asm code is loading the kernel starting at sector 5. I think you want dd if=$(KERNEL_BIN) of=$(BOOTLOADER_IMG) bs=512 seek=4 conv=notrunc so that matches (seek=4 would be sector 5)

After you get all the straightened out then you should be able to start debugging the code that gets you into long mode. One of the first problems there is that you don't enable CR4.PAE before hand which is a requirement to enter long mode.

Note: I'm not sure why your first stage is loading 34 sectors.

There really is a big mishmash of things going on. Maybe the code showing here is not what you are using and I am still spinning my wheels. The code is doing one thing and the disk image is built for something else. The code in second_stage.asm seems to think the kernel starts at sector 5 and you put it physically on disk somewhere else. I don't know if your disk image is wrong or the code. Whatvere it is it all has to match.

Other things that are concerning is that your second stage can be up to 3 sectors long (1536 bytes) from the way you wrote second_stage.asm. However if it ever gets to be more than 512 bytes it will get partially clobbered when you read the kernel to 0x8000. That's because second stage starts at 0x0000:0x7e00 and will go up to just before 0x0000:0x8400.

@MichaelPetch Thank you for bearing this with me, I have updated the code snippets. The kernel now will should be loaded at 0x8500 & protected mode should be working (tested via lldb). However, the problem seems to be at either paging fault or kernel doesn't get written at the designated address. PS: I haven't changed the memory address for kernel from 0x8000 to 0x8500 yet. Thank you very much!

The help I gave you was just to get you further along. A well you didn't enable PAE (and ensure PGE) were enabled before getting into long mode. Your paging code is all wrong and doesn't actually map anything at all. So as soon as paging is enabled it faults. It doesn't even get to the part where it jumps to the higher half. If you created a Github project I could push changes to your project to get it working. I was able to get it to function here.

I used this first_stage.asm: https://pastebin.com/11rzMsar , second stage: https://pastebin.com/gJTUFugf . I used these commands to build the image (you can update the seek= in your Makefile accordingly: https://pastebin.com/UUAFL6hL

Most of the changes are related to paging and entering long mode in the second stage file.

Sorry for not reaching back to you. This really helped me out. After some researching, I've understand more about this. Could you please post the solution to this problem? Again, I really really appreciate your help!

@MichaelPetch Nevermind what I said earlier, I tried refactoring the code and it didn't work out so well. The problem is enabled_protected_mode doesn't actually enable the protected mode. I'll make a new question if you ever want to look at it again
